# Automatically adding [/] or [%] to the end of TODO tasks

Tags: org-mode

I'm using org-mode and I like to keep track of my TODO tasks.

EG: Here is what my TODO's look like

```
TODO [#B] Implement stuff [%]
```

If I currently add a TODO I just get the following;

```
TODO
```

I have to then set a priority, add a title and add the [%] at the end, I would like to have it automatically set to priority [#B] and put the [%] on the end, is this possible?

Comment: How about using `org-capture`?  http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html  You can customize `org-capture-templates`.  You may also wish to consider using `tags` at the end of the heading -- *instead of* `[%]` -- to take advantage of many organizational features that are built-in to `org-mode`.  A tag looks like `:hello:`  And let's not forget the leading asterisk(s) at the beginning of the heading to designate the level of the tree/subtree.